# How do Catholics interpret Isaiah 2:4?

Tags: catholicism, eschatology

I quote the verse:

> He [The Lord] shall judge between the nations, and shall decide disputes for many peoples; and they shall beat their swords into plowshares, and their spears into pruning hooks; nation shall not lift up sword against nation, neither shall they learn war anymore.

The chapter this verse comes from seems to describe an earthly reign of God, in contradiction with the Catholic doctrine.

Any idea how the verse could be interpreted?

Comment: I really don't see how this could contradict Catholic doctrine. Which Catholic doctrine would you be referring to?

Comment: There seems to be a cultural motivation from some Protestant sects to over emphasize Eschatology and push the “Are you Saved?” and “ will you be left behind” Agenda.  In fairness, the Catholic Church focuses very little on eschatology except to mention it briefly at each and every Mass in the Creed.  It is to bad really, because the topic is actually interesting and fun, even if it lacks some of the glamour of the fundamentalists man made traditions.

Answer (score 1):

A Catholics Answer

Isaiah's prophetic warning was for Judah and Jerusalem. Isaiah 2:1 It was fulfilled with the Babylonian captivity. It was again fulfilled when the Romans toppled Jerusalem. Isaiah's warning is for all God's children, even today. Do not allow your gluttonous desire for things of this world kill your desire to worship and serve the LORD your God, by doing His will among you.

There is no mention what so ever in Isaiah Chapter 2 of an earthly reign of God.

Pre-melenialism Rapture Theology is a man made tradition and a false doctrine.

Comment: * [2:4] Once the nations acknowledge God as sovereign, they go up to Jerusalem to settle their disputes, rather than having recourse to war.

Answer (score 1):

It could happen, definitely could happen and we, Catholics pray for the coming of the Kingdom every day. We also pray that Christ will return every day (hopefully not in Winter). And these are two different and similar things.

The Kingship of God is that we live with Christ as our sovereign.  The Kingdom is what Jesus was preaching about while He built His Church. Fr. Richard Simon explains it that way on his radio show on relevant radio, we are to preach the kingdom and build the church and a lot of people outside the Catholic Church think we're called to build the kingdom. I think they're forgetting what Jesus said about His Kingdom not being of this world. (Jn 18:36).

The other problem with interpreting that Isaiah is saying that the Earthly Reign of God has already started is that in one sense it has.  Everything that Isaiah said about Jesus has already come to pass and a lot still has to.

Finally, it should be noted that there can be no Catholic Interpretation of Sacred Scripture. You can only get a whiff of what it means.  Some of what this is talking about seems like it should be considered in the eternal sense; Interpreted as what it means with regard to our final destination.

The closest I can do is give you the tiny notes the US Catholic Bishops conference wrote for that verse

> Once the nations acknowledge God as sovereign, they go up to Jerusalem to settle their disputes, rather than having recourse to war

http://www.usccb.org/bible/is/2:2#29002004-1

And that would suggest that this has not come to pass, since all nations have not acknowledged God as sovereign.